# Subscribe to photo events

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to receive a notification in my application when the user takes a picture from outside my application? For example, when I take a picture using my button on the side of the phone, I will like to get that picture automatically also in my application and process it there.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot directly receive notifications when the user takes a picture.

However, you can [integrate with the Pictures Hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202966%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), so that the user can easily share the picture after they take it, if they decide to do that.